# Override Function in ODOO15

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

With the new changes in odoo15. I am not able to override a function in Javascript. I have created a custom module and imported the required.

I want to override _executeReportAction function

```
 import {download} from "@web/core/network/download";
 import {registry} from "@web/core/registry";
 import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";
 import {actionService} from "@web/webclient/actions/action_service";


 async function _executeReportAction(action, options) {

  }
```

so how to do it

Comment: What about the [official doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/patching_code.html)?

Comment: Do you need to handle a new report type?

Comment: Yes I want it for a new report type (ZPL) @Kenly

Comment: Try to add a report handler for `zpl` reports

Answer (score 1):

The `_executeReportAction` function will first try to execute [ir.actions.report handlers](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js#L1016), so instead of patching the function add a `zpl` report handler.

You can check the OCA [report_xlsx](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/blob/15.0/report_xlsx/static/src/js/report/action_manager_report.esm.js#L8) module which defines a report handler for `xlsx` reports

***Original Code:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import {download} from "@web/core/network/download";
import {registry} from "@web/core/registry";

registry
    .category("ir.actions.report handlers")
    .add("xlsx_handler", async function (action, options, env) {
        if (action.report_type === "xlsx") {
            const type = action.report_type;
            let url = `/report/${type}/${action.report_name}`;
            const actionContext = action.context || {};
            if (action.data && JSON.stringify(action.data) !== "{}") {
                // Build a query string with `action.data` (it's the place where reports
                // using a wizard to customize the output traditionally put their options)
                const action_options = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(action.data));
                const context = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(actionContext));
                url += `?options=${action_options}&context=${context}`;
            } else {
                if (actionContext.active_ids) {
                    url += `/${actionContext.active_ids.join(",")}`;
                }
                if (type === "xlsx") {
                    const context = encodeURIComponent(
                        JSON.stringify(env.services.user.context)
                    );
                    url += `?context=${context}`;
                }
            }
            env.services.ui.block();
            try {
                await download({
                    url: "/report/download",
                    data: {
                        data: JSON.stringify([url, action.report_type]),
                        context: JSON.stringify(env.services.user.context),
                    },
                });
            } finally {
                env.services.ui.unblock();
            }
            const onClose = options.onClose;
            if (action.close_on_report_download) {
                return env.services.action.doAction(
                    {type: "ir.actions.act_window_close"},
                    {onClose}
                );
            } else if (onClose) {
                onClose();
            }
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    });
```

In the code above they merged the [_triggerDownload](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js#L959) and [_getReportUrl](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js#L930) functions into one function.

Comment: Thank you for .. it works for me but is there any way to stop downloading the ZPL report @kenly

Comment: What do you mean by: "stop downloading the ZPL report"?

Comment: I mean I do not want ZP file get downloaded in user pc - @kenly

Comment: What do you want to do with the ZP report?

Comment: I made a module to direct print ZPL, The problem is with preventing the report to be downloaded in user pc @kenly

Comment: The report handler function above is used to download the report, you need to write your own code to directly print the report.